# code converter not found (UTF-8 to LATIN1) after update to rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm converting application from rails 3.0 to rails 3.2 . In this application I'm using csv_builder und use selectable output character sets.
The character code of my application in UTF-8.

The charactersets were called "UTF-8" and "LATIN1" in rails 3.0, csv_builder (2.1.0).
After update to rails 3.2, csv_builder (2.1.1), I got the error

> code converter not found (UTF-8 to LATIN1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to rename the target charcter set to

> ISO-8859-1

so the name of the character set seems to have changed to the more precise ISO name